# Phishing OnHover images/link in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My company recently purchased the Services of Phishme.com. This company claims that they can tell if a person "hovers" over an image/link in an email. We are running outlook 2016 and exchange server 2013. I highly doubt this is possible, does anyone know if this is possible and a show me whatever technique that they are using?

Answer (score 0):

When an image is loaded the image server can log the IP and time that each image request comes in. These can be correlated with a spear phishing campaign. That should be self evident. If there was a dynamic image of size 0x0 was loaded on hover that could be traced in this same way, transparently. This is just one way, there could be more.

To block this data from being collected you can block images from being loaded in Outlook:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-email-messages-15e08854-6808-49b1-9a0a-50b81f2d617a

The article linked here states:

> Advantages of blocking automatic picture downloads include:
> ...
>
> ...Helping to keep malicious code from damaging the data on your computer.

This suggests that there might be scripting that could be leveraged here.

Outlook 2016 uses Word 2016 to render HTML\CSS elements.

According to this article there is also a JavaScript API for Office\Word\Outlook:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office

If you could leverage the Office scripting API or OLE object functionality all sorts of things become possible. There have been multiple exploits based on this concept.

EXAMPLE: https://arstechnica.com/security/2015/12/outlook-letterbomb-exploit-could-auto-open-attacks-in-e-mail/

> The winmail.dat file includes instructions on how to handle
> attachments embedded within it. "When the value of the
> 'PidTagAttachMethod' [within winmail.dat] is set to ATTACH_OLE (6),"
> Haifei wrote, "the 'attachment file' (which is another file contained
> in the winmail.dat file) will be rendered as an OLE object."

Of course, any attack that would work against Word 2016 would also work against Outlook 2016.

I can't tell you for sure what technique they are using, they could be using something novel or unpublished. I would not doubt that they can. Test them. Ask for the data.